# Construct new column to be used with window functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make the column called `result` in the table below.

It connects the prior `Type` = 'P%' to the latest `Type` = 'S%' within each `cat`.

All `Type` = 'P%' that are not followed by a `Type` = 'S%' (ordered by `Date`) should be set to NULL within each `cat`.

| dates | Cat | Type | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-12-31 | 1 | S_0 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | P1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | P2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | S_1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | P3 | 2 |
| 2020-01-06 | 1 | P4 | 2 |
| 2020-01-07 | 1 | S_2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-08 | 1 | P5 | `NULL` |
| 2020-01-09 | 1 | P20 | `NULL` |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | P6 | 3 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | P7 | 3 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | S_3 | 3 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2 | P8 | `NULL` |
| 2020-01-05 | 3 | P9 | 4 |
| 2020-01-06 | 3 | P10 | 4 |
| 2020-01-07 | 3 | S_4 | 4 |
| 2020-01-08 | 3 | P11 | `NULL` |

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (dates date,cat smallint,Type varchar(20))
insert into tab values 
('2019-12-31',1,'S_0'),
('2020-01-01',1,'P1'),
('2020-01-03',1,'P2'),
('2020-01-04',1,'S_1'),
('2020-01-05',1,'P3'),
('2020-01-06',1,'P4'),
('2020-01-07',1,'S_2'),
('2020-01-08',1,'P5'),
('2020-01-09',1,'P20'),
('2020-01-01',2,'P6'),
('2020-01-02',2,'P7'),
('2020-01-03',2,'S_3'),
('2020-01-04',2,'P8'),
('2020-01-05',3,'P9'),
('2020-01-06',3,'P10'),
('2020-01-07',3,'S_4'),
('2020-01-08',3,'P11');
```

Any one got a clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Product or Cat ?   OrderType or Type ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion John, it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks lptr, I believe this solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by lptr!

```
CREATE TABLE tab (dates date,Product  smallint,OrderType varchar(20))
insert into tab values 
('2019-12-31',1,'S_0'),
('2020-01-01',1,'P1'),
('2020-01-03',1,'P2'),
('2020-01-04',1,'S_1'),
('2020-01-05',1,'P3'),
('2020-01-06',1,'P4'),
('2020-01-07',1,'S_2'),
('2020-01-08',1,'P5'),
('2020-01-09',1,'P20'),
('2020-01-01',2,'P6'),
('2020-01-02',2,'P7'),
('2020-01-03',2,'S_3'),
('2020-01-04',2,'P8'),
('2020-01-05',3,'P9'),
('2020-01-06',3,'P10'),
('2020-01-07',3,'S_4'),
('2020-01-08',3,'P11');



select *,
case when
min(case when ordertype not like 'p%' then ordertype end) over(partition by product order by dates
rows between current row and unbounded following) is not null 
then 
isnull(nullif(count(case when ordertype like 's%' then 1 end) over(order by product, dates rows between unbounded preceding  and 1 preceding)
, 0),1)
end as result
from tab
order by product, dates
```